# Angular UI Grid: How to select a row directly after loading new data?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This .selectRow() on line #2 doesn't work:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = MyResource.query();
$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow( $scope.gridOptions.data[0] ); // Select first row
```

I'm guessing it doesn't work because the grid hasn't finished refreshing yet, or hasn't even started refreshing because it is still waiting for data from `MyResource.query()`.

The following doesn't work either and I have no idea why:

```
$scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows(MyResource.query());
$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow( $scope.gridOptions.data[0] ); // Select first row
```

What's going wrong exactly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);

Comment: This results in an empty grid

Comment: the function modifyRows does not exists for me, but no error shown either when I call it. Its like nothing happened..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have already solved this, but I think the problem is that you are trying to select the row before it is there. You can do this in two steps. First load the data and then broadcast an event when it is done, and then get the row when you listen to the broadcast.
So step 1 would be some thing like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = MyResource.query();
$rootScope.$broadcast('data_loaded', $scope.gridOptions.data);
```

And then listen to the broadcast:

```
 $scope.$on('data_shared',function(event, data) {
    $scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow( $scope.gridOptions.data[0] ); 
   });
```

I hope it helps.